# Python Beautifulsoup4 parsing multiple tables

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to parse multiple tables from this website i.e
http://www.cboe.com/strategies/vix/optionsintro/part5.aspx

Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('http://www.cboe.com/strategies/vix/optionsintro/part5.aspx', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'table  oddeven  center  padvertical  cellborders  mobile-load'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

However, it keeps generating me with this message :

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Would anyone mind helping me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'table  oddeven  center  padvertical  cellborders  mobile-load'})
```

This will return a list of table tag, it's a `list object` or `ResultSet`, the `find_all()` can only be used in tag object

```
import bs4 as bs

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('http://www.cboe.com/strategies/vix/optionsintro/part5.aspx', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    td = [td for td in tr.stripped_strings]
    print(td)
```

out:

```
['Bid', 'Ask']
['VIX Dec 10 Call', '6.40', '6.80']
['VIX Dec 15 Call', '2.70', '2.90']
['VIX Dec 16 Call', '2.30', '2.40']
['VIX Dec 17 Call', '1.80', '1.90']
['VIX Dec 18 Call', '1.45', '1.55']
['VIX Dec 19 Call', '1.15', '1.25']
['VIX Dec 20 Call', '0.95', '1.00']
['Bid', 'Ask']
['VIX Dec 10 Call', '9.30', '9.70']
['VIX Dec 15 Call', '4.90', '5.20']
['VIX Dec 16 Call', '4.30', '4.60']
['VIX Dec 17 Call', '3.70', '3.90']
['VIX Dec 18 Call', '3.10', '3.30']
['VIX Dec 19 Call', '2.65', '2.75']
['VIX Dec 20 Call', '2.25', '2.35']
```

This website only contain two tables which are what we need, so just find all `tr` will return the information we need.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = 'http://www.cboe.com/strategies/vix/optionsintro/part5.aspx'
response = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

tables = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'table  oddeven  center  padvertical  cellborders  mobile-load'})
for table in tables:
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        print(row)
```